# Sibling view prevents recyclerview from scrolling when made clickable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My screen consists of a ConstraintLayout with two children. The one child is a RecyclerView which takes up the entire screen. The other child is another ConstraintLayout that contains a TextView (the screen is actually more complex than this, but I'm reducing it to something here to make it easier to comprehend). The child ConstraintLayout is positioned over the RecyclerView and scrolls up whenever you scroll the RecyclerView. This is done using a scroll listener on the RecyclerView and re-adjusting the Y position of the child ConstraintLayout. The child ConstraintLayout needs to be clickable.

The problem I am having is that if you try scrolling the RecyclerView by first touching down on the child ConstraintLayout, the scrolling will not work. The click event handler for the child ConstraintLayout will work, however.

From my understanding of how Android handles touch events, if a view returns false in its onTouchEvent handler, that view will not get notified of any further motion events. So theoretically, if my child ConstraintLayout returns false in its onTouchEvent handler, the RecyclerView should still get the scroll motion events.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:background="#55338855">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboardConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/dashboard_initial_animation_start"
        app:showPaths="false">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/contentRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideWelcome"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1.0" />

        <ReservationCard
            android:id="@+id/reservationConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/dashboard_reservation_card_background_color"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtSearch">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtReservationHeader"
                style="@style/AppTheme.Label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_screen_reservation_card_headline"
                android:textColor="@color/dashboard_reservation_card_text_color" />

        </com.sinnerschrader.motelone.screens.dashboard.ReservationCard>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is my custom ConstraintLayout (ReservationCard):

```
class ReservationCard : androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout {

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector

    init {
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(GestureListener())
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (ev?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)
            return true
        } else if (ev?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)
            return false
        } else {
            super.onTouchEvent(ev)
            return false
        }
    }

    private inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
        override fun onFling(p0: MotionEvent?, p1: MotionEvent?, p2: Float, p3: Float): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onScroll(p0: MotionEvent?, p1: MotionEvent?, p2: Float, p3: Float): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onLongPress(p0: MotionEvent?) {
        }

        override fun onDown(p0: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onShowPress(p0: MotionEvent?) {
        }

        override fun onSingleTapUp(p0: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The child ConstraintLayout is positioned over the recyclerview and scrolls up whenever you scroll the recyclerview" so your child view also scrolls with the recycler view? and issue you are facing is when u click/focus child view and then scroll recycler view it's not working?can you share a ScreenShot/video for better understanding?

Comment: The child ConstraintLayout and the recyclerview are siblings. Code (not shown) allows the child ConstraintLayout to scroll whenever the recyclerview scrolls (which is what I want). But I also want the child ConstraintLayout to be clickable. I am able to get the code to do one or the other (scroll or be clickable). I have not been able to get it to do both.

Comment: in `onTouchEvent` if (ev?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)
            performClick()
            return false
        }
you don't need any other code in `onTouchEvent` and i can't see any use of gesture detector anyway's !